# PC does not recognize XBox 360 controller connected through Play & Charge Kit

Tags: windows-7, windows, xbox360, game-controller

I wanted to hook up my wireless XBox 360 controller to my PC running windows 7.  I'm trying to use the Play & Charge kit since I already had that laying around.  I plugged it in and Windows recognize it and installed it.  It registers in Device Manager as "Xbox 360 Wireless Controller via Play & Charge Kit".  The controller also has the 1st quadrant lit.

However, I can't seem to make this work with any games.  I installed the "Microsoft Xbox 360 Accessories" kit from MS website, and I run the Accessories Status app and it doesn't recognize that the controller is connected.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong out there?

Comment: Just buy a wireless adapter elsewhere since Microsoft stopped putting wireless adapters and HD adapters in the xbox sets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Play & Charge kit by itself is not by enough to use Xbox 360 controllers on your PC.  You also need the [Wireless Gaming Receiver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_accessories#Wireless_Gaming_Receiver).  Using the Play & Charge Kit would mean that you don't have to sync your controller each time with your 360 and PC, but it won't allow you to actually play games without the receiver.